# On master branch git says im ahead of master by 10 commits, my colleagues 10 commits and one contains an error

Tags: git

I finished working on my branch and just wanted to update with master. Now I have tried so many options I can remember it all. I did a git pull, had a divergence of 1200 and 200 commits in each direction. That didnt look good so I did a git reset --hard and git pull origin. On rebasing it brought merge conflicts so skipped the rebase.
Now I am at a stage where it says im ahead 10 commits.
In the git history I can see my colleagues have made 10 commits past the origin/master.

My next ticket is just a oneliner in a file so i thought id try this.. Created a new branch, did my changes and pushed. Now I see my commit includes their 10 commits, and one of them is throwing an error.
My question is Firstly, should I reset to the master/origin or the master (10 commits ahead) Secondly, how to avoid pushing their errors?  I don't mind loosing my personal changes, just want this to match up without pushing anything.

Comment: Their errors have already been pushed, or else you wouldn't have been able to pull them from the remote.

Comment: If you want your local repo to match the remotes, you probably want `git fetch; git reset --hard @{u}` to reset to the version on the remote.

Comment: Thank you that was apparently just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

In my case Williams answer of "git fetch; git reset --hard @{u}" did the trick.  After that I just deleted the old branch and started fresh.